# Cannot assign "'Math'": "SubjectClas.subject" must be a "Subject" instance

Tags: python, django

So, I have some problems witn my django project. I`m wanting to assign Subject from droplist(that formed from database called Subject) to another database called SubjectClas but I`m keep getting this error.  Any suggestions? Thanks.
Cannot assign "'Math'": "SubjectClas.subject" must be a "Subject" instance.

My  code from html

```
{% block add %}
<form action="{% url 'marks:addsubject' class.id%}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <select required name="sub">
                {% for d in subjectslist %}
                  <option value='{{d.id}}'>{{d.SubjectName}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <button type="submit">готово</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My  models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Class(models.Model):
    classtitle = models.CharField('класс', max_length = 50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.classtitle
class Subject(models.Model):
    SubjectName = models.CharField('Предмет', max_length =50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.SubjectName
class SubjectClas(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    clas = models.ForeignKey(Class, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
```

My views.py

```
def addsubject(request, classid):
    try:
        a = Class.objects.get( id = classid )
    except:
        raise Http404("Http404")
    SubjectClas.objects.create(subject = request.POST['sub'], clas = a)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `subject` is a `ForeignKey` to the `Subject` model, so by passing a string, that will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subject` is a `ForeignKey` to the `Subject` model, so by passing a string, that will not work.

You can however create or obtain a `Subject` object, for example with [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def addsubject(request, classid):
    subject, __ = Subject.objects.get_or_create(name=request.POST['sub'])
    SubjectClas.objects.create(subject=subject_id, clas_id=classid)
    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
```